# Como evitar la Inyección sql en un ContentValues Java Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, contentvalues

tengo este ejemplo

variables

```
string  m_descrip    = " ejemplo de texto descrip ";
string  m_ot_id      = " ejemplo de texto ot id";
string  m_modificado = 1;
```

y el método es el siguiente.

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put("DESCRIP", m_descrip);
        args.put("OT_ID", m_ot_id);
        args.put("MODIFICADO", m_modificado);
        return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + id, null) > 0;
```

pero como evito  por ejemplo que el usuario ingrese el valor con '

por ejemplo

```
string  m_descrip    = " ejemplo de error  des '  descrip  ";
```

y teniendo en cuenta que tiene que devolver un booleano osea  si se actualizo correctamente .. devuelve true.. sino false.

Answer (score 2):

Lo que necesitas es validar que el `String` que esta introduciendo no contenga ese símbolo en especifico, podrías solo colocar algo como:

```
if(m_descrip.contains("'")){
    //do something
}
```

Pero eso no seria muy útil ya que si ingresa otro símbolo similar que te cause problemas seria lo mismo, tendrías que validar símbolo por símbolo. Lo que te recomiendo que hagas para este caso es usar expresiones regulares, de esta forma validas los símbolos de forma general, y creas un error si el `String` contiene alguno de estos símbolos que no deseas que estén en el mismo o evitar que se ejecute una función si se cumple la condición, de esta forma:

```
if (!m_descrip.matches(".*[!@#$%^&*,/\\\\()¿~_'<>:;+.=?-].*")) {
   EditText.setError("el texto contiene un símbolo invalido");
   // o si usas el Layout del EditText
   LayoutEditText.setError("el texto contiene un símbolo invalido")
}
```

Bien con esa expresión regular estamos evaluando en el texto la existencia de alguno de los símbolos que se encuentran en los corchetes, esta parte específicamente:

**[!@#$%^&*,/\\()¿~_'<>:;+.=?-]**

Y con los `".*"` a los extremos del corchete, queremos decir, que evalúe a lo largo del texto si existen, un ejemplo para ver mejor esto es:

**"Texto de prueba que contiene &$%! valores invalidos"**

Este texto sera rechazado por la expresión regular, por que los símbolos están en medio del texto, es decir, hay valores validos antes y después de los símbolos.

Si quieres evaluar si el texto contiene alguno de los símbolos que están dentro del corchete desde el comienzo hasta el final del mismo, seria de otra forma, en vez de comenzar con `".*"` comenzarías con `^` y en vez de finalizar con `".*"` seria con `"$"`, para entender un poco mas sobre expresiones regulares puedes revisar [aquí](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371415?hl=es).

Por ultimo, si quieres hacer la conversión sin importar que el usuario introduzca el texto de forma correcta, y que sea corregido automáticamente puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
    for (int i=0; i<m_descrip.length(); i++) {
        String s = String.valueOf(m_descrip.charAt(i));
        if(s.matches("^[!@#$%^&*,/\\\\()¿~_'<>:;+.=?-]$")){
            m_descrip = m_descrip.replace(s, "");
            i--;
        } 
    }
```

De esta ultima forma, recorremos letra por letra de `m_descrip`, es evaluado por la expresión regular, si coincide, se reemplaza por `""`, es decir, `null`, y guardado en el mismo `m_descrip`, de tal forma que al terminar el recorrido del `for` el `m_descrip` quedaría sin ninguno de los símbolos existentes en la expresión regular utilizada para evaluarlo.